# javascript index of object is string and not int

Tags: javascript, string, object, counter

I'm wondering why does my `pageCounter` in the pages object (see below) is taken as a string instead of an int?
Why does javascript does not interpret the variable and uses the name of the variable as a literal string?

```
for (var i in stories){
        //reset the counter when it hits the number of stories per page
        if (counter >= divsByPage) {
            counter = 1;
            pageCounter++;
        }

        //turn all the stories off
        //stories[i].style.display = "none";

        //insert a new story under a page array
        pages.push({pageCounter:stories[i]});

        counter++;
    }
```

`console.log(pages[1]);` outputs `Object { pageCounter=[1]}`.

Comment: What makes you think it's going in as a string?

Comment: I would like to get the end result on something like: `[{0:[{story}, {story}, {story}], 1:[{story}, {story}]}];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object field names -- which is what `pageCounter` in `{pageCounter:stories[i]}` is -- are always strings (or string-like). The `pageCounter` in `{pageCounter:stories[i]}` has nothing to do with the `pageCounter` you are incrementing.

Comment: So object fieldnames can never be ints? pageCounter is a global defined var before the loop ...

Comment: Well, sort of, if you use it as an array. But you can't set it the way you are doing. See Dennis' answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this if you want to use `pageCounter` as a variable instead of a name:

```
var object = {};
object[pageCounter] = stories[i];
pages.push(object);
```

Comment: mmm...not sure if this would solve the problem because in the end what I was looking for is something like: `[{0:[{story}, {story}, {story}], 1:[{story}, {story}]}];` Am I going in the right direction? I need an object that contains a few arrays of objects...